# Image from sqlite database used for face recognization using python

Tags: python, sqlite, face-recognition

I have store the image in sqlite3 database using BLOB datatype and I need to extract that image for facial recognition . I have been using face recognition package to do so. The problem is i am not able to use extracted image for encoding and other operation. So, I think I have to change the datatype of the image for further processing but I am not able to find so.

[image: Extacting image for encoding]

The error for the code is:

```
RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to properly read the face images.

There are multiple libraries for that operation. For instance: `opencv`, Pillow, `skimage`, etc.

Here is an example of how you can read the face image:

```
from PIL import Image


for face in data:
    face_array = Image.open(face)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I am still having some error reading the Blob image. 
When I used the above code I face these error:    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I have used  c.execute("INSERT INTO known_face(image,username) VALUES(?,?)", (sqlite3.Binary(image), username)) to insert an image into database.